# nested fragment throwing null

Tags: android, android-fragments

The end goal is to click from a list view stored in one fragment, 
open another fragment that has a nested fragments view [AnswerFragment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O7nb3.jpg),
here the nested fragments should consist of two fragments, top portion being the question text from the list and the bottom half being the answer. Right now I've managed to pull off the communication bit of passing the question text from the list to the single question fragment (which should be stored in the top half of the answer fragment) However it's inflating the single question layout over the answer fragment like this [SingleQuestionFragment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OMoYS.jpg)
    .

```
   public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements AllQsFragment.Communicator {

private DrawerLayout mDrawer;
private Toolbar toolbar;

private NavigationView mNVDrawer;
private ActionBarDrawerToggle drawerToggle;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //Set a Toolbar to replace the ActionBar.
    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


    mDrawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawerToggle = setupDrawerToggle();

    mDrawer.setDrawerListener(drawerToggle);

    //Find our drawer view
    mNVDrawer = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nvView);
    //Setup drawer view
    setupDrawerContent(mNVDrawer);

}

private ActionBarDrawerToggle setupDrawerToggle() {
    return new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawer, toolbar, R.string.drawer_open, R.string.drawer_close);
}

private void setupDrawerContent(NavigationView navigationView) {
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(
            new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {
                    selectDrawerItem(menuItem);
                    return true;
                }
            });
}

public void selectDrawerItem(MenuItem menuItem) {
    //Creat a new fragment and specify the planet to show based on
    //position
    Fragment fragment = null;

    Class fragmentClass;
    switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.nav_first_fragment:
            fragmentClass = AllQsFragment.class;
            break;
        default:
            fragmentClass = AllQsFragment.class;
    }

    try {
        fragment = (Fragment) fragmentClass.newInstance();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    //Insert the fragment by replacing any existing fragment
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.flContent, fragment).addToBackStack("addedToBackStack").commit();

    //Highlight the selected item, update the title, and close the drawer
    menuItem.setChecked(true);
    setTitle(menuItem.getTitle());
    mDrawer.closeDrawers();
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    //The action bar home/up action should open or close the drawer
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            mDrawer.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
            return true;
    }

    if (drawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred
    drawerToggle.syncState();
}

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    //Pass any configuration change to the drawer toggles
}


@Override
public void sendText(String data) {
    SingleQuestionFragment questionFragment = (SingleQuestionFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("fragmentQ");
    if (questionFragment != null) {
        questionFragment.changeText(data);
    } else {
        SingleQuestionFragment fragment = new SingleQuestionFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString("text", data);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.flContent, fragment)
                .addToBackStack(null).commit();
        fragment.sentText();
    }
}

}
```

**fragment_answer**

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.victor.nattest5.AnswerFragment">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/q_fragment">

    </FrameLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/a_fragment">

    </FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

**AnswerFragment**

```
public class AnswerFragment extends Fragment {

public AnswerFragment() {
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    insertNestedFragment();
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_answer, container, false);

}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
}

private void insertNestedFragment() {
    Fragment childQFragment = new SingleQuestionFragment();
    FragmentTransaction transaction = getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    transaction.add(R.id.q_fragment, childQFragment,
                    "fragmentQ").commit();

    Fragment childAFragment = new SingleAnswerFragment();
    FragmentTransaction transaction1 = getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    transaction1.add(R.id.a_fragment, childAFragment, "fragmentA").commit();
}

public static final AnswerFragment newInstance() {
    AnswerFragment frag = new AnswerFragment();
    return frag;
}
}
```

**SingleQuestionFragment**

```
public class SingleQuestionFragment extends Fragment {
TextView questionTxt;
String stringtext;

public SingleQuestionFragment() {
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_single_question, container, false);
    questionTxt = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textView_q);
    return v;
}

public static final SingleQuestionFragment newInstance() {
    SingleQuestionFragment frag = new SingleQuestionFragment();
    return frag;
}

public void changeText(String data) {
    questionTxt.setText(data);
}

public void sentText() {
    new BackGroundTask().execute();
}

private class BackGroundTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
        Bundle b = getArguments();
        stringtext = b.getString("text");
        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String result){
        changeText(stringtext);
    }
}

}
```

When I run this with the debugger, the app runs without crashing. However, it shows this line is null ->
SingleQuestionFragment questionFragment = (SingleQuestionFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("fragmentQ");

I know what null means, I just don't understand how to fix this problem. Somewhere in my code I think I'm inflating an extra layout or possibly inflating the wrong container.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to offer any suggestions because your app is complex and not all of the code is posted.  It's also not clear whether any of the posted code includes changes you've made to try and work around the problem.  For example, I don't understand the need for `BackGroundTask`.  There is no reason to perform that processing in a background thread.  Did you do this as a workaround to add some delay to the processing?

You didn't post the code that calls `MainActivity.sendText()`, or explain what causes it to be called.

If I understand your post correctly, in `sendText()`, the call to `findFragmentByTag()` is returning null and that is an error.  Are you expecting to find the `SingleQuestionFragment` added in `AnswerFragment`?  If so, you won't find it because you are searching the fragments held by the manager of MainActivity only.  The search does not include fragments held by the managers of child fragments. In other words, the search does not recursively search the fragment tree.

Comment: Yes, findFragmentByTag() is returning null. I see your point now, this is happening because I'm using getSupportFragmentManager() which is pointing to the context of main activity. To my understanding the fragment to fragment interface communication pattern, had to be addressed on the main activity because that's where the fragments are being displayed. As I see getParentFragment() wont work in the main, do you have any suggestions on getting around this? Maybe implementing the interface strictly in the fragments, if possible. Also I see your point in not needing the ASyncTask method

Comment: I don't know much about your overall design.  I think I'd suggest managing all the fragments from the main activity and not using nested fragments.  In addition to adding and removing fragments in the layout, you can control their visibility with `FragmentTransaction.hide()` and `FragmentTransaction.show()`.

Comment: Is there a way to access nested fragments via appcompatactivity?

Comment: Yeah but isn't it inefficient to have all fragments running  at the same time? If you look at the picture I supplied for the Answer Fragment, you can see my need for nested fragments